.NET MAUI MySQL Connection Working on Windows but Failing on Android
I am developing a .NET MAUI application with a login page that verifies user credentials from a MySQL database hosted on FreeSQLDatabase. The code works perfectly when I run it on a Windows machine, but it fails to connect to the database when running on an Android device.
Here is the relevant code for my login page:
using System;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using Microsoft.Maui.Controls;

namespace Zakazivanje.Pages
{
    public partial class LogInPage : ContentPage
    {
        public LogInPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        
        private async void btnLogIn_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(MainPage.connectionString))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        await conn.OpenAsync();
                        string email = entEmail.Text;
                        string secretKey = entPassword.Text;

                        string query = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_persons " +
                                       "FROM person " +
                                       "WHERE email = @Email " +
                                       "AND secret_key = @SecretKey";
                        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", email);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SecretKey", secretKey);

                        object result = await cmd.ExecuteScalarAsync();

                        if (result != null && result != DBNull.Value)
                        {
                            int countPersons = Convert.ToInt32(result);
                            if (countPersons > 0)
                            {
                                labTitle.Text = "aga"; // Found matching person
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                labTitle.Text = "aha"; // No matching person
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            labTitle.Text = "Query returned null or empty result."; // Handle no result scenario
                        }
                    }
                    catch (MySqlException ex)
                    {
                        labTitle.Text = $"MySQL Error: {ex.Message}";
                        Console.WriteLine($"MySQL Error: {ex.Message}");
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        labTitle.Text = $"Error: {ex.Message}";
                        Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (MySqlException mysqlEx)
            {
                labTitle.Text = $"MySQL Error: {mysqlEx.Message}";
                Console.WriteLine($"MySQL Error: {mysqlEx.Message}");
            }
            catch (TypeInitializationException tieEx)
            {
                labTitle.Text = $"Type Initialization Error: {tieEx.Message}";
                Console.WriteLine($"Type Initialization Error: {tieEx.Message}");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                labTitle.Text = $"General Error: {ex.Message}";
                Console.WriteLine($"General Error: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }
    }
}


When I run it, I get this error: Error: TypeInitialization_Type, MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Replication.ReplicationManager.
Environment Details:
MySQL.Data: 8.4.0
System.Data.SqlClient: 4.8.6
.NET: 7.0
Database Host: FreeSQLDatabase
The connection to the MySQL database works on Windows but fails on Android. I have verified that the app has internet access on Android.
Double-checked the connection string and ensured it's correct.
Ensured that the app has the necessary internet permissions on Android.
The app targets .NET 7.0.
The database is hosted online, accessible from other applications and platforms.
Has anyone faced a similar issue or have any insights on what might be causing the problem? Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Please reconsider the use of direct database connections on Android. While the linked-to question is for JDBC, the same sorts of concerns will hold for other direct database connection solutions.

What does fail to connect mean? What is the exact error message? Btw, it is unusual to directly connect to a mysql database over the Internet as it is not secure and the connection is not always supported by network devices optimised for http.

@CommonsWare, thanks for answering. I read the article, and it really makes sense. Could you please provide me with some materials so I can create that web service?

@Jason that solves my problem, thanks for pointing that out
